# Eigenvalue problem and its complex conjugate

Tags: linear-algebra, physics, hermitian-matrices

The following problem comes from a classical-mechanics treatment of lattice vibrations. It's essentially a linear algebra question, though, so I thought it would be on-topic here.

If it may be assumed that the vibrations of atoms about their equilibrium positions in a crystal lattice are small (in some sense), it can be shown the problem of finding their frequencies $\{\omega\}$ and polarizations $\{\varepsilon\}$ is equivalent to solving the eigenvalue problem

$
\begin{equation}
\omega_q^2\varepsilon_q=D_q\varepsilon_q
\end{equation}
$

where the dynamical matrix $D$ is Hermitian and $q$ is a label which characterizes the allowed vibrations. By taking the complex conjugate of the above, replacing $q\rightarrow-q$, and exploiting the additional symmetry $D_{-q}=D_q^*$, it follows that

$
\omega_{-q}^2\varepsilon_{-q}^*=D_q\varepsilon_{-q}^*
$

*i.e*. $\varepsilon_{-q}^*$ and $\omega_{-q}^2$ are also eigenvectors/values of $D_q$. The book I'm reading now claims we can set

$
\omega_q^2=\omega_{-q}^2
$

as well as, modulo a complex phase

$
\varepsilon_q=\varepsilon_{-q}^*
$

I understand that we *can* make this choice and both eigenvalue problems will be satisfied, but is it necessary? Experiments can directly measure $\omega$ as a function of $q$ -- I should think that if $\omega_{q}^2\ne\omega_{-q}^2$, there should be measureable consequences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is correct, but I'll post my progress on this question. If someone could let me know if it looks OK, that would be much appreciated.

Since $\{\varepsilon_{-q}^*\}$ and $\{\varepsilon_q\}$ are the eigenvectors of a Hermitian matrix $D_q$, we can expand any other vector in a series of them. In particular

$
\begin{align}
\varepsilon_q&=\sum_{q'}B_{q'}\varepsilon_{-q'}^*\tag{1}\\
\varepsilon_{-q}^*&=\sum_{q'}C_{q'}\varepsilon_{q'}\tag{2}
\end{align}
$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$

$$
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle
\varepsilon_q=\underbrace{\sum_{q'}B_{q'}}_{S_B}\sum_{q''}C_{q''}\varepsilon_{q''}
=S_B\sum_{q'}C_{q'}\varepsilon_{q'}
\end{equation}
$$

Taking the dot product of both sides with $\varepsilon_{q''}^*$ gives

$$
\delta_{q,q'}=C_{q'}S_B
\implies
C_{q'}=\frac{\delta_{q,q'}}{S_B}\tag{3}
$$

Note that $S_B\ne0$ since by summing the equation on the left-hand side above we find $S_BS_C=1$ where $S_C=\sum_qC_q$. Substituting $(3)$ into $(1)$

$$
\varepsilon_{-q}^*=\frac{1}{S_B}\times\varepsilon_q
$$

The requirement that both $\{\varepsilon_{-q}^*\}$ and $\{\varepsilon_q\}$ be orthonormal bases fixes $|S_B|^2=1\implies S_B=e^{-i\phi}$. Hence $\varepsilon_{-q}^*$ are $\varepsilon_q$ are equal modulo a complex phase factor. The equality of the spectra now follows readily from the eigenvalue equations

$$
\begin{align}
\omega_q^2\varepsilon_q&=D_q\varepsilon_q\\
\omega_{-q}^2\varepsilon_q&=D_q\varepsilon_q
\end{align}
$$

Subtracting the above two equations gives

$$
\left[\omega_q^2-\omega_{-q}^2\right]\varepsilon_q=0
$$

and hence $\omega_q^2=\omega_{-q}^2$ by the linear independence of the $\{\varepsilon_q\}$.